# How to achieve that "ui-sref" be conditionally executed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to validate certain condition before the browser follow the link dynamically created by ui-router.

I was looking into `$rootscope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ..)` but I have no access to the `controller.$scope` from there. I also need to use this in several places in the application and would be cumbersome.

Keep in mind that `ui-sref` is linked to `ui-sref-active` (work together), so i can't remove `ui-sref` and, by say, to use `$state.$go('some-state')` inside a function called with `ng-click`.

The condition should be evaluated inside a `$scope function` and on `on-click event` (before-transition with the ability to cancel it)

I need something like this:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="somestate" ui-sref-if="model.validate()">Go Somestate</a>
</li>
```

I tried:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="somestate" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">Go Somestate</a>
</li>

<li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="somestate" ng-click="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()">Go Somestate</a>
</li>
```

And

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="somestate">
       <span ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">Go Somestate</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Even

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="somestate" onclick="return false;">Go Somestate</a>
</li>
```

But does not work.

[SANDBOX](http://plnkr.co/edit/tSnoaS?p=preview)

Comment: Basically you want to test a certain condition when a user visits that link, and then decide whether he can continue with that link or not?

Comment: yes, but at the application level there is a state change. link not literally. need so I can prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags-in-angularjs/14165848#14165848) inspired me to create a directive that allows me to interrupt the chain of events that end up changing state. For convenience and other uses also prevents the execution of ng-click on the same element.

**javascript**

```
module.directive('eatClickIf', ['$parse', '$rootScope',
  function($parse, $rootScope) {
    return {
      // this ensure eatClickIf be compiled before ngClick
      priority: 100,
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function($element, attr) {
        var fn = $parse(attr.eatClickIf);
        return {
          pre: function link(scope, element) {
            var eventName = 'click';
            element.on(eventName, function(event) {
              var callback = function() {
                if (fn(scope, {$event: event})) {
                  // prevents ng-click to be executed
                  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                  // prevents href 
                  event.preventDefault();
                  return false;
                }
              };
              if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
                scope.$evalAsync(callback);
              } else {
                scope.$apply(callback);
              }
            });
          },
          post: function() {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**html**

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="somestate" eat-click-if="!model.isValid()">Go Somestate</a>
</li>
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/AKQasLfnvZFkKdHz3nEQ?p=preview)

Comment: They should really include this functionality. It could be renamed to `ui-sref-disable`. Consider opening a pull request, @OneWay!

Comment: This is just awesome.  Thanks for this tid bit.  I agree with @DesignerGuy, it should be `ui-sref-disabled`

Comment: @DesignerGuy ...we did it, and this is what they answered us to do: copy this module :-D :-D :-D ----  here the link ---->   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1489#issuecomment-91098823

Comment: This is a workaround. There are simpler, effective, generic ways to handle this. Refer to any other answer.

Comment: For me, it's not working when we enable minified version of this directive :(

Comment: This doesn't look like it would prevent a user from focusing on the link using the keyboard. What happens with screen readers?

Answer (score 29):

You can use a scope function that will either returns :

- no state
- an existing state

  like so :

HTML :

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="{{checkCondition()}}">Go Somestate</a>
</li>
```

JS scope :

```
$scope.checkCondition = function() {
    return model.validate()
        ? 'someState'
        : '-' // hack: must return a non-empty string to prevent JS console error
}
```

`href` attribute will be created only when the function returns an existing state string.

Alternatively, you could do a (ugly) :

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="somestate" ng-if="model.validate()">Go Somestate</a>
      <span ng-if="!model.validate()">Go Somestate</span>
</li>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i still get a console error when trying your `checkCondition()` method. It says `Could not resolve '-' from state 'home'`

Comment: I like this answer because it is the fastest way to done.
`ui-sref="{{condition ? '.childState' : '.'}}"`

Comment: @chovy a '.' by itself instead of '-' will return the current state

Comment: To prevent an error:    $rootScope.$on("$stateNotFound", function (event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (unfoundState.to == '-') { event.preventDefault(); return; }});

Comment: @chovy I had the same issue and put it in `href="checkCondition()"` instead after returning `return $state.href('login', {}, {absolute: true});`

Answer (score 12):

The easiest workaround to conditionally achieve routing without tinkering with directives, scope etc was a workaround i found here - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1489

**`<a ui-sref="{{condition ? '.childState' : '.'}}"> Conditional Link </a>`**

Answer (score 7):

You can always double up on the element and show/hide conditionally

```
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
          <a ng-show="condition1" style="color: grey">Start</a>
          <a ng-hide="condition1" ui-sref="start">Start</a>
    </li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ts4yGW?p=preview

Comment: This is not helpful to me, because I don't want to gray-out the button. I simply want to popup an alert that says "You are about to navigate away, are you sure?"

Answer (score 3):

No need for complicated directives or hacks. The following works fine and allows for specific handling on click of non-`sref` items:

```
<a 
  ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="{{item.sref || '-'}}" 
  ng-click="$ctrl.click(item, $event)"
>...</a>
```

And in the controller, a simple click handler for the items which don't have an `item.sref`:

```
this.click = function(item, event) {
  if (!item.sref) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //do something else
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers to [How to dynamically set the value of `ui-sref`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349731/dynamically-set-the-value-of-ui-sref-angularjs) you can create a function in your scope for building the URL:

```
$scope.buildUrl = function() {
  return $state.href('somestate', {someParam: 'someValue});
};
```

And then conditionally append it to the link with [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

```
<a ng-href="{{ someCondition ? buildUrl() : undefined }}">Link</a>
```

As you can see in the demo below, `ng-href` does not add the `href` attribute if value is negative.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <a ng-href="{{ condition ? 'http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif' : undefined}}">This is the link</a>
  <br>
  <label for="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" ng-model="condition">
    Link active?
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for future reference I wanted to offer an alternative solution since I didn't see it in any of the answers so far.

**Desired:**

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="somestate" ui-sref-if="model.validate()">Go Somestate</a>
</li>
```

**Potential solution** (template):

```
<li ng-class="{ active: state.current.name === 'somestate' }">
    <a ng-click="navigateToState()">Go Somestate</a>
</li>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.state = $state;
$scope.navigateToState = navigateToState;

function navigateToState() {
  if ($scope.model.valid) {
    $state.go('somestate');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for those who still need `ng-click` working on `ui-sref` component or its parents.

My solution is to use `href` instead of `ui-sref` and to modify [Emanuel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636705/2014288) directive a bit to be able to stop `href` and `ng-click` calls separately.

[Planker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9TkzPNAnDfI4lEzzQzT5?p=preview).

Though it has a few restrictions:

- will not work with `ui-sref`
- you should have different urls for each state because of previous restriction
- `ui-sref-active` will not work either

Answer (score 0):

For the binary case (link is either enabled or disabled), it "now" (since ~2018) works like this (prevents the click and sets it to disabled):

```
<a ui-sref="go" ng-disabled="true">nogo</a>
```

and for other tags as well:

```
<span ui-sref="go" ng-disabled="true">nogo</span>
```