# Opening external url with $state

Tags: angularjs

Is this possible to navigate to external URL in angular using $state provider?

like `$state.href('external', 'http://stackoverflow.com')`

Comment: can't you use something like `$window.location.href` [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) or `$document.location` to change the current page.

Comment: that would be an option, but I wonder if I can somehow use the state provider

Comment: What benefit will using the `$state` give you?

Comment: true probably gives no benefits. what for are then that $state.href directives?

Comment: did you mean `ui-sref`? fyi, `$state` is a service, the directives are ways to bind javascript to the DOM

Comment: Straight from the docs, the href on `$state` is: A url generation method that returns the compiled url for the given state populated with the given params.

Comment: ok ill make it with doc location.thanks!

Comment: Could you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30221248/2435473