# how to make $urlRouterProvider.otherwise route to external url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have .js file as below

```
routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
    var $state = $injector.get('$state');
    var path = $location.protocol();
    if (path == 'http') {
       $state.go('external');
    }
    else {
        return '/home';
    }
});

$stateProvider

    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'routing.html'
    })
    .state('external', {
        onEnter: function ($window) {
         $window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');
        }
    });
```

});

above code works fine when path != 'http', it will redirect to routing.html. But when path == 'http', it should call external state and redirect to external url. Here path == 'http' condition is not working. How to call external url here? and in state I am calling external onEnter. Can I do it without OnEnter?

Comment: I'm a little confused on the purpose of what you are trying to do.  `otherwise` is meant for non-matching routing hits.  The first hit to your site will most likely match the otherwise function.  What is the interest of sending them to another site?

Comment: I am trying to do conditional otherwise. my target is incase my if condition is true then it should redirect me to external url(in this case google.com) and if it is false then redirect to internal .html file. I am able to achieve false condition. My question is incase true then how to redirect to external url?

Comment: @aparnakm I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30221248/2435473

Comment: Just a question, what's the goal of it ? Forbid http connection ? a redirect from server-side would be far more easier, http/https is not the concern of the front-end

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
   var protocol = $location.protocol();
   if (protocol == 'http') {
      window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');
   }
   else {
       return '/home';
   }
});
```

Comment: though i don't see the point of the   var $state = $injector.get('$state'); when $state is not used :)

Comment: @unflores I want to call state 'external' on true. I don't want to give url directly. is it possible?

Comment: @walfrat, yeah, I just modified his original function.  I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit different but probably something like this will work :)

```
$rootScope.on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState){
    if(toState.name == 'external'){
         event.preventDefault();
         window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');
    }
});
```