# Combine $window and $stateProvider to open a new browser tab window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***app.js***

```
 $stateProvider.state('tenant.propertyGoogleMap', {
            url: '/PropertyGoogleMap',
            templateUrl: '~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/propertyGoogleMap.cshtml',
            menu: 'PropertyGoogleMap.Tenant'
        });
```

***html***

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.propertyGoogleMap()">
                    @L("PfMap")
                </button>
```

***js***

```
 vm.propertyGoogleMap = function () {
                $window.open('tenant.propertyGoogleMap', '_blank');
            };
```

Could you tell me how to combine both `$window` and `$stateProvider` to open a new browser tab when user clicks the button ? When I try as shown above then it gives `404 error`.Thanks.

Comment: It cannot work because window.open() takes in input an URL not a uiRouter state name. The method does not know anything about uiRouter and uiRouter states.

Comment: @Andrea OK then could you tell me how to do this task ? Thanks.

Comment: @Sampath I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30221248/2435473) would help you to redirect to external domain from ui-router context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
vm.propertyGoogleMap = function () {
                    var url = $state.href('tenant.propertyGoogleMap', {}, {absolute: true});
                    $window.open(url, '_blank');
                };
```

Where $state is the [uiRouter $state service](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

The method `href` with option `absoulte: true` returns the absolute URL of the given state.

Comment: Having an issue.That is, url should be like this `http://localhost:6240/Application#/tenant/PropertyGoogleMap` but when I use your above solution its like this `http://localhost:6240/#/tenant/PropertyGoogleMap` and due to that, the desired page is not being loaded. Do you know why ? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind when I use the `absolute: false` then it works fine.Thanks a lot :)