# use ui-sref only if the parameter is defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Here is my following code:

view:

```
<div class="single-user" ui-sref-active="activeState" ui-sref="app.usersingle({id:item[0].id})">    
    <li class="userTicket">Total: {{item[0].nbtickets}}</li>
</div>
```

and in app.js:

```
 .state('app.usersingle',{
            url:"/user:id",
            templateUrl: "views/single_user.html",
            controller:"userCtrl",
            reloadOnSearch:true
        })
```

I would like to be able to click on my `div` only if `item[0].id` is defined (from my `ui-sref`).
How can i do this. Because when the `item[0].id` is not defined it load the next page with errrors. What i want is just that when `item[0].id` is not defined it just stay in the page and do nothing.
Is that clear explanation ?

Comment: call a function on click and then redirect conditionally from there

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973530/disable-ui-sref-based-on-a-condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do conditional stuff over `ui-sref` itself, where you could redirect to other state when `Id` is present other redirect to other state `.`

```
ui-sref="{{ item[0].id ? 'app.usersingle({id:item[0].id})': '.'}}"
```

Took a reference from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28774864/2435473)

Comment: For me it doesn't work, because page reloads when ui-sref is set to '.' . For me using '-' instead of '.' works as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25601646/5613768 . I use version 0.2.18 and have no error.