# AngularJS: clicking on active tab removes location hash tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI-router with sticky states. For the hash tag functionality below, I use $location.hash() as the getter/setter.

I have a tabbed AngularJS app where there are sticky states (so when I switch between tabs, the controllers don't reload). So if I click on one of the tabs, my URL becomes '/tab1/#subtab1'. I can switch to another part of the app and the URL will become say, '/tab2', and when I switch back to tab1, the URL stays '/tab1/#subtab1' where I left off. This is all fine.

**However, when I click on my active main tab more than once** (though I doubt 99% of eventual users will do this), the 'subtab1' part gets removed, and the URL just becomes '/tab1#'.

The $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart') event doesn't detect this event. I have tried putting a ng-disable or trying to intercept this event somehow, but seems I am looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Can you recreate this in a jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Fixed using the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600071/how-to-achieve-that-ui-sref-be-conditionally-executed